# example with iteration of git notes

Tags: c, libgit2

I'w writing an application using libgit2 and stuck with iteration git-notes.

Create a sample of GIT repository with a single commit with attached note:

```
$ mkdir git-repo
$ cd git-repo
$ git init
$ echo "file" > file
$ git commit file -m "file"
$ echo "notes" > notes
$ git notes add -F notes 32bc2d65241d3b34fb55758362d5bcb4483f36b9
$ git notes list                                                  
cf88e040a4be8874952acfaa44f627718bcfd547 32bc2d65241d3b34fb55758362d5bcb4483f36b9
$ git notes show 32bc2d65241d3b34fb55758362d5bcb4483f36b9
notes
$
```

Create a source file with code:

```
#include <git2.h>        
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)     
{                                                    
        const char* notes_ref = "refs/notes/commits";              
        const char* repo_path = "./git-test";                                                             
        if (!(git_repository_open_ext(   
        NULL, repo_path, GIT_REPOSITORY_OPEN_NO_SEARCH, NULL) == 0)) {
        exit(-1);                                    
        }                                            
        printf("%s is a GIT repository\n", repo_path);
        git_libgit2_init();
        git_repository *repo = NULL;
        int rc = 0;
        rc = git_repository_open(&repo, repo_path);
        if (rc < 0) {
                const git_error *e = giterr_last();
                printf("Error %d/%d: %s\n", rc, e->klass, e->message);
                exit(rc);
        }
        git_oid *annotated_id, *note_id;
        git_note_iterator *iter;
        rc = git_note_iterator_new(&iter, repo, notes_ref);
        if (rc < 0) {
                const git_error *e = giterr_last();
                printf("Error git_note_iterator_new() %d/%d: %s\n", rc, e->klass, e->message);
                exit(rc);
        }
        while(git_note_next(note_id, annotated_id, iter) != GIT_ITEROVER) {
                const char *note_msg;
                git_note *git_note;
                git_note_read(&git_note, repo, notes_ref, note_id);
                note_msg = git_note_message(git_note);
                printf("%s\n", note_msg);
        }
        git_note_iterator_free(iter);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
}
```

Compile source code to binary:

```
gcc notes.c -g3 -O0 -o notes -L/usr/local/lib -lgit2 -I/usr/local/include
```

And application segfaults when I'm running it:

```
$ gdb ./notes
(gdb) run
./git-test is a GIT repository

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000d0e8cb21f06 in git_oid_fromstrn () from /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so.11.0
Current language:  auto; currently minimal
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000d0e8cb21f06 in git_oid_fromstrn () from /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so.11.0
#1  0x00000d0e8cb22117 in git_oid_fromstr () from /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so.11.0
#2  0x00000d0e8cb13f97 in process_entry_path () from /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so.11.0
#3  0x00000d0e8cb13c0a in git_note_next () from /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so.11.0
#4  0x00000d0c2cab249a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7f7fffff0218) at notes.c:31
(gdb)
```

What is wrong with example?

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know the gitlib API, but this cannot be correct:

```
git_oid *annotated_id, *note_id;
[...]
while (git_note_next(note_id, annotated_id, iter) != GIT_ITEROVER) { ... }
```

The variables are uninitialized pointers that will be passed **by value** into the function. They're as useless as arguments as possible; they would work *only* if `git_note_next` was an evil, vicious macro that has side effects on its arguments.

Perhaps the API is meant to be used with

```
git_oid annotated_id, note_id;
[...]
while (git_note_next(&note_id, &annotated_id, iter) != GIT_ITEROVER) { ... }
```

---

In fact your mistake seems to be **not using `-Wall` all the time**:

```
gittest.c: In function ‘main’:
gittest.c:33:17: warning: ‘note_id’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                 git_note_read(&git_note, repo, notes_ref, note_id);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gittest.c:30:15: warning: ‘annotated_id’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         while(git_note_next(note_id, annotated_id, iter) != GIT_ITEROVER) {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: libgit2 API says, that git_note_next() three pointers as arguments (https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/note/git_note_next). Why you decide that first two arguments should be double pointers? I didn't get it.

Comment: @SergeyBronnikov what double pointers? Did you even read my code?

Comment: Yep, you are exactly right.  libgit2 takes a pointer to a `git_oid` here.  The OP needs to have allocated one, somewhere, to pass in.